# How do I unfollow someone on Pinterest?

Tags: pinterest

I'm trying to find the option that allows me to un-follow my Facebook friends on Pinterest.  At the place where I would logically conclude an "unfollow" button would show up, I'm greeted only with a greyed-out "Following."

Below screenshot taken from the `/invites/facebook` URI, where you can expand your already subscribed friends.

[image: List of people following]

*Is there a way to un-follow people on Pinterest?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pinterest is tricky with this.

Use the following link `http://pinterest.com/<yourUsername>/following/`

The way the un-follow button works is a tad decieving but it works

[image: Looks Disabled]

It looks disabled even on rollover, but clicking it does indeed un-follow a user.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  You're quite right that the button is a bit hidden and definitely appears to be disabled.  They really don't want you to stop following people I guess!